# Remove an anchor point's bezier handle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anchor-point

In Illustrator CC, is there a way to remove / retract bezier handles from a point?

See below picture, the two handles between the corner points are useless and I'd much rather just have a straight line.
[image]

The one method I know to achieve this is using the pen tool and `alt` clicking on the corner, but that retracts both sides of the bezier, so I'd have to redraw the other side where I do want the handle.

Is there a way to just retract a specific anchor point's bezier handle?

Comment: Here's [how you do it in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155752/359). Not sure if it works in AI as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### 1. Select the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

### 2. Click on the end of the handle you want to remove.

[image]

If you want to remove both handles (i.e. convert to a corner point) just click the anchor point itself.

You can also convert the anchor point to a corner point by <kbd>alt</kbd> + clicking on the anchor point with the Pen Tool selected or using the *Convert Selected Anchor Points To Corner* button in the Control panel.

Comment: FYI it is now called the "Anchor Point Tool". They removed "convert" from the name of the tool.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great plugin from Astute Graphics called [VectorScribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) in which you can retract the handles to any specific number, including zero.

[image: PathScribe panel]

Comment: Good to know. Also costs 70 bucks.

Comment: Yea, might be overkill if that's all you want from  it, but it has lots and lots of tools that I get a lot of use out of.

Comment: I own the tool and appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0):

So I think there might be a simpler way to quickly remove all handles and convert to the point. If you goto:

**Object > Path > Simplify...**

[image: Simplify... dialog box with 'straight lines' unchecked]

If you then **check 'Straight Lines'**, it converts all points to corners, creating straight lines!

[image: Simplify... dialog box with 'straight lines' checked. Converts all points to corners!]

Hope this helps!!